# Can I use discrete ordinal variable as an outcome in Linear Regression? If not what other choices do i have?

Tags: regression

firstly thank you for taking the time for reading this and thank you even more if you can help me. So, i have an outcome variable with 11 options where 1 means that the person is totally fine and 11 means the person can't get out of bed. So i have to use this variable as an outcome variable in a regression analysis for my research project, where the independent variables will be 20 symptoms (binary yes/no), and basically we are trying to see if having anxiety for example predicts worst health. However, my variable is not continuous but discrete, and it is also ordinal with 11 levels. I have to use linear regression. So i would like to ask you is that even a correct analysis to use with this variable, and if not, do you have any suggestions? Also, my sample is 1500 individuals, i read that it doesn't matter that my data are not normally distributed with this big sample, is this correct? Also, normality of residuals is violated. Any suggestions? Thank you very much for any help in advance, just a desperate msc student here!

Answer (score 3):

If your outcome variable is *ordinal* and not normally distributed, you should not be running a linear regression; an ordinal regression is more appropriate. Regardless of sample size, it does matter that your data are not normally distributed. Moreover, ordinal data *is not* continuous.

The following extract, about using linear models with ordinal outcome, is from Christensen (2015):

> This approach is in a sense over-confident since the data are assumed to contain more information than they actually do. Observations on an ordinal scale are classified in ordered categories, but the distance between the categories is generally unknown. By using linear models the choice of scoring impose assumptions about the distance between the response categories. Further,
>   standard errors and tests from linear models rest on the assumption that the response, conditional on the explanatory variables, is normally distributed (equivalently the residuals are assumed to be normally distributed). This cannot be the case since the scores are discrete and responses beyond the end categories are not possible. If there are many responses in the end categories, there will most likely be variance heterogeneity to which *F* and *t* tests can be rather sensitive. If there are many response categories and the response does not pile up in the end categories, we may expect tests from linear models to be accurate enough, but any bias and optimism is hard to quantify.

Edit: Summarising the above, if your ordinal outcome appears normally distributed, you may get similar results from a linear regression to those from an ordinal regression, but the more *non-normal* the data appears, in general, the more the estimates will differ. In your case, from what I read from your question, the normality assumption is not met, so the case for running an ordinal regression, as opposed to a linear one, is strengthened.

What software are you using? You can run a cumulative link model, a regression model for ordinal data, using package "ordinal" in R, see [here](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/ordinal/ordinal.pdf), [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_tutorial.pdf), and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/vignettes/clm_intro.pdf). You can also use the function polr from the MASS package [consider this guide](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/).

Comment: Good points, but sometimes ordinal regression allows for the possibility of less information than we actually have. For example, although it is hard to say the difference between 1 and 2 is the same as the difference between 2 and 3 on some theoretical underlying scale, the difference between 2 and 3 is certainly not 1,000 times larger than the difference between 1 and 2 in almost any practical application.

Comment: For me the issue is that the outcome is not really continuous. Regarding the ratings, you can assume flexible thresholds in an ordinal regression, but you do not have to. For example, you can impose restrictions on the thresholds, such as symmetry or equidistance.

Comment: I don't know much about ordinal regression so thanks for letting me know about flexibile thresholds. Not sure, but can't the residuals of outcome variable be more or less continuous? The simulations I've seen (don't have them at my fingertips) mostly indicate that regression works well with ordinal data such as likert scales.

Comment: @DavidLane Of course, depending on the location of responses, Likert scales can **appear** to be normally distributed, and even with the ones that do not, in practice, you can still run a linear regression. Typically, if the outcome appears normal, the linear regression will give more or less the same results as ordinal (direction of effects, significance levels), but as you reduce the number of categories (1), and the distribution becomes more skewed (2), the ordinal regression will  outperform the linear.

Comment: @MichaelR Michael, thank you very much for your invaluable help, much appreciated. I am using SPSS but when i understand what i have to do, i will search and perform my analysis and interpret the results, the conceptualization behind is what confused me. So, apparently the normality is a important, so i would like to ask you whether the transformation technique might be appropriate? The outcome is a Likert-type with 11 levels, it seems ordinal to me, but my supervisor discusses it as discrete. I would also like to ask whether i can run the ordinal regression with an outcome with 11 levels? Tnx

Comment: @SlavZhelev Slav, if the outcome can be ordered or ranked then you should treat it as ordinal; your supervisor may think that discretely measured responses can be ordinal. You can try to transform the data to make it appear more normal, for example you can log transform the outcome if it is positively skewed, but depending on the data this will not always work, and you will be imposing assumptions on the distance between ratings. Regarding your last question, yes you can run ordinal regression with 11 categories.

Answer (score 1):

Yes linear regression is a good idea for a start.

The question is not so much whether the dependant variable is discrete or continuous, but whether it represents a quantity where natural order means something (1<2<3<...<11) and whether the outcome is expected to depend on the independent variables in a monotonous (and ideally linear) way :

- the more anxiety increases, the more the outcome increases
- the more gym increases, the more the outcome decreases...
- ...

And this seems to be realistic in your case. Whether your variable is continuous or discrete does not change very much the appropriateness of linear regression.

Linear regression is meaningless when the dependant variable are numbers that represent categories arbitrarily. Like a job :

- 1=butcher
- 2=policeman
- 3=cook
- ...

Typically this case would require multinomial logistic regression.

A question that may appear in your case is whether linearity is realistic enough or if a non linear regression would be better : like a generalized linear model. But discrete or not discrete is not much important.