# What regression type for Normal DV and count data IV (with lots of 0s)

Tags: regression, least-squares, zero-inflation

I'm performing regression on subjects' response to a question on a 1-5 likert scale (1=low, 5=high, etc)- This is the DV and its continuous and normally distributed.  The IV is a count of how many times they were exposed to a stimuli (a count of the number of times).

So the IV is count data.... It's not normally distributed and a full third of the scores are zero (the average is around 3, though the max is 20).
Is there any specific type of regression I could run to look at the effect of this stimuli? If the count data was the DV I'd do a zero inflated negative binomial regression or something like that, but in this instance the count data is the IV... Would simple OLS regression be suitable?

Comment: In your title you say the DV is normal. In your text you say it is on a 1 to 5 scale. 

It can't be both. Which one is it?

Answer (score 4):

Your DV is not continuous or normally distributed -- do not be constrained by the normality assumption -- I would suggest you run an ordinal regression model (see: [Can I use discrete ordinal variable as an outcome in Linear Regression? If not what other choices do i have?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283067/can-i-use-discrete-ordinal-variable-as-an-outcome-in-linear-regression-if-not-w/283082#283082)). If you treat ordinal data as continuous you make the erroneous assumption that your data contains more information than it actually does (consider reading this tutorial by Bürkner and Vuorre https://psyarxiv.com/x8swp/).

Your predictor variable does not have to be normally distributed.

Comment: Upvoted for excellence of the answer.